# Typescript - No type when requiring a local module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I work on a NodeJS project with Typescript, and I can't get to get it work with autocomplete and CommonJS.
Here my configuration:

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "lib": [],
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./dist/typings/",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "strict": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

*jsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "XXXX",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "module": "dist/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack --watch",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "types": "dist/typings/main.d.ts",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
   ...
}
```

*webpack.config.js*

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'main.ts'),
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
  },
  target: 'node',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

My TS code *src/main.ts*

```
export class Api{
  private apiKey: string;
  private secretKey: string;

  constructor(apiKey: string, secretKey: string) {
    this.apiKey = apiKey;
    this.secretKey = secretKey;
  }

  public test() {}
}

export namespace Api{
  export interface IRequestParameters {}

  export enum ERequestMethod {
    POST = 'POST',
    GET = 'GET',
    PUT = 'PUT',
    DELETE = 'DELETE',
  }
}
```

And when I try to import the build JS, the code is working, but there's no autocomplete on VSCode:

```
const Api = require('../dist/main');
const api = new Api(process.env.API_KEY, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
```

Do you have any idea ? I tried so many options ...

Comment: I didn't get it why you need webpack config and why you are trying to import JS-file instead of TS? And if you import TS-files you should use `import some from './somemodule'` instead of using `require`. Or am I missing something?
`

Comment: My project has some deps, and I want to propose a single file at the end, so Webpack is my bundler. Also, the `require` is on a Node `.js` file to test the autocompletion.